# Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected at line XX []$[] $

Tags: boxes, autonum

I know there were a lot of questions regarding underfull hbox, but in my case error

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected at line 5
 []$[]    $
```

point to line

```
5: \begin{document}
```

How can hbox be underfull if compilation of the document has not even started?

EDIT: after inspection I have found out that `autonum` package is creating this error.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{autonum}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bug in package `autonum`, as @Heiko Oberdiek mentioned in his answer in question [autonum-does-not-work-with-eqnarray](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68207/autonum-does-not-work-with-eqnarray/68223#68223).

Please report the bug to the maintainer of `autonum`.

Comment: I've reported the bugs to the email provided with the autonum package.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning. I just uploaded version 0.3.1 which should fix this bug.